# Central Force Problem

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, physics, classical-mechanics

Given an equation $F(x)$ that represents the magnitude of some force $F$ that varies with distance from the origin, is it possible to derive the equation of motion $p(t)$ of a point particle $P$ placed within this force field with arbitrary initial position and initial velocity?

Answer (score 2):

Sure, just solve: $m\ddot{p}=F(p)$, with $p(0)=p_0$ and $\dot{p}(0)=v_0$.

Comment: Would it be possible to derive this equation with respect to time instead of position?

Comment: @J_Psi This _is_ with respect to time. More explicitly (i.e. writing down the actual time independence), the equation that Alex has given you above is exactly the same as $$m\frac{d^2p}{dt^2}(t) = F(p(t)),\quad p(0) = p_0, \quad \frac{dp}{dt}(0) = v_0$$